# Why does the first chapter of Toni Morrison's "Playing in the Dark" open with this Eliot verse in Black Matters?

Tags: t-s-eliot, intertextuality, toni-morrison

As an epigraph a T. S. Eliot verse appears at the beginning of Toni Morrison's *Playing in the Dark: Whiteness and the Literary Imagination*:

> I am moved by fancies that are curled
> Around these images, and cling:
> The notion of some infinitely gentle
> Infinitely suffering thing.
>
> T. S. Eliot
> from “Preludes, IV”

Why did Morrison choose this verse and how does it connect with the rest of the chapter **Black Matters**?